# C: static int gets strange value

Tags: c, variables, static, int

(changed name of variable from original question to fit the actual code)
I'm new to C and I'm implementing a queue.
The error is with the `static int head=0` variable. It's incremented by 1 each time dequeue() is called. The error seem to occur when the queue is dequeued and function get_person() is called. The head-variable is then as it seems getting a high random number, like **23423449**. I have no idea where this comes from. However if I get rid of the "static" keyword so variable is declared as `int head=0`, it works fine. How come?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Your variable should be inside a .C file, not inside header (there you should put its definition marking it as "extern").

Comment: The variable is not in the header file, it is in the c-file. And it's only used inside that very file.

Comment: By making the variable static in the header you would be giving every file that includes the header its own personal version of the variable. Setting the variable in one file will have no effect on the versions in any other file

Comment: Could xcode be lying? Try printing the value out

Comment: No, I've printed its value as well. Code is coming.

Comment: @user1121487: may be you're having a local variable with same variable name `variable1` as global, which is getting high preference than global variable. It would be better if you post your code..

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Comment: @user1121487: are you sure `head` is not declared anywhere else in the program.

Comment: Absolutely sure. This is basically so far the entire program. The main file just calls these functions.

Comment: @user1121487 could you post your main function too? and is the main function inside queue.c?

Comment: The main-function is in it's own c-file. I've just put test data in the main function, testing enqueue, dequeue etc. It's very basic.

Comment: @user1121487: The above code looks clear to me. since, no one posted the right answer, give us some more information to debug your code.

Comment: @user1121487 the above code looks fine. I believe you are either using an undefined variable in you main function or you are trying to access one of the static variables defined in queue.c i.e: int main() { ... printf("head=%d\", head); return 0; } this does not work because head is static in queue.c and it cannot be accessed by the main function, which is declared in a different file. However, it is hard to say, since we cannot see the main function.

Here's sth to try : add <printf("head=%d\n",head);> at the end of your dequeue function and call only dequeue in main. results must match.

Comment: Put the static definition of the person array AFTER the static definition of head, and I think you'll find head is no longer being changed

Comment: It's still changing...

Comment: @user1121487 are the elements in person struct of type char* or char[]? if they are char[], then my guess would be you are overrunning the person array as mentioned by others. I would also suggest using strncpy over strcpy, it is much safer. if the elements are char*, then make sure they point to an allocated memory before using populating them.

Comment: I would use printf statements to see exactly which line is causing the value to be changed. Pasting printf("%d:%d\n",\_\_LINE\_\_,head) will show you the line number of where it changed

Comment: Just realized that if (tail == QUEUE_MAX_SIZE) is wrong, it should be: if (tail == QUEUE_MAX_SIZE-1)... doh.

Comment: So the person array was being overwritten, but not by the strcpy. Ok, but in that case defining the head before the array should have stopped it from being overrwritten

Answer (score 5):

> using a "global" variable in top of a **included file**: `static int variable1=0`

This clearly indicates, that you don't understand what the `static` keyword means on the global scope. In the global scope, outside of a function, static means, that the variable is visible to only the code within the compilation unit the variable has been defined in.

Now if you define a static variable in a header, each compilation unit that includes that header will have its own variable of that name. So your program is littered with many identically named variables each specific to the compilation unit it's in.

I think what you actually want is an non-static, `extern` declaration in the header, and exactly *one* compilation unit actually defining the variable.

Comment: The variable is in the c-file, that is included through it's header-file. The variable is only used inside the c-file.

Comment: @user1121487: You wrote put the variable in the header file. So what is it? How about you add your source code to the answer so we can see, what you actually have there. Any way, there's no point in having global scope `static` declarations or definition in a header file.

Comment: No I didn't, I said I it was in top of the included file. Sorry not being clear, I simply meant if was in in a external c-file not in the main file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overrunning your person array

One of the strcpy functions is going beyond the bounds of the buffers in the person object, and overwriting the head variable. I would guess the tail and nbr_elem are going too.

You should check that the number of characters you are copying does not exceed the buffer lengths, or use strncpy.

Comment: How is that possible? The head value is only altered by incrementing +1 or set to zero. And the error ONLY occurs when the static keyword is being used....

Comment: The head value can be changed if you write beyond the area defined by the person array. Without the static the compiler might put the variable somewhere else. Add a static variable before the head, set it to 0, and see if that is changed also. Or just change the char[] buffers to std::strings, which is a good idea anyway

Comment: @user1121487 except you can't use std if this is C, but you should still prevent the strcpys from writing too much data by checking the length of the data first, or using strncpy

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a global static variable in file `A.c`, it means this variable is only available within the scope of this `A.c` file. See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Since you haven't posted any code, and you are metioning using the same variable in a different file (e.g. `B.c`), it seems like it is invoking an `undefined behavior`, which explains the random number your program is printing.

If you wish to use the variable in a different .c file, you should not make it static.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling strcpy without checking that the values you are trying to write will actually fit inside the allocated space inside the person struct.

What is most likely happening is you are writing beyond the allocated memory, and your strcpy is actually overwriting the value of head. strcpy will keep writing until it hits a null terminator ('\0').

If you were to run this in valgrind (a useful tool for finding this type of problem in large programs) it would probably tell you you have invalid writes occurring.

C assumes you know what you are doing, as long as you have access to the memory you can do with it as you please :)